# Get Isotope to not load specific images at all

Tags: javascript, css, replace, onload, jquery-isotope

I'm working with Isotope and I have a lot of images in it.

The problem is that when visiting my one page website from a smartphone it takes quite a bit to load the page as isotope load all the images thumbnails as soon as isotope itself loads.

So, basically I want to hide/not load all the images that mustn't be shown if it's category isn't clicked and what I did was use two workarounds:

1. set the figure to display:none so that it doesn't show the void where it was supposed to be and the other images can actually occupy that space
2. set the img src to about:blank so that it doesn't load until it's category is clicked

then when the link "Click me!"(category) is clicked the figure gets set to display:block and the img src gets replaced by the real image path.

style:

```
#showfigure{
display:none; !important
}
```

body:

```
<a href="#" data-filter=".imgtoshow" onclick="javascript:showAll();">Click me!</a>

<figure id="showfigure" class="filter imgtoshow">

<img id="showimg" src="about:blank" alt="">
</figure>
```

script:

```
<script>
function showAll() {

document.getElementById("showfigure").style.display = 'block';

$("#showimg").attr("src","example.jpg");

};
</script>
```

Now, the only way I got it to work with multiple figures/images was giving each figure and image it's own id (showfigure1, showfigure2, showfigure3 etc... and showimg1, showimg2, showimg3, etc...) as using the same id only works for the first figure/img in the code.

Am I missing something?

I tried replacing the path of the img src like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6Gds/28/

But I can't get it to do the same with the onclick function from the link "Click me!", and anyways there's the same problem with the ids.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: An ID is unique identifier, you can't use the same one for different elements.

Comment: Oh right, but I just tried with class and it doesn't work! So the only thing I can do is create multiple ids for every element?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/F6Gds/29/

Comment: That fiddle was about replacing a part of the img src, I mean that the class part doesn't work with isotope. If I put getElementsByClassName(".showfigure") and change the figure class to showfigure it doesn't work. But, could you do the same fiddle with a button instead of hover over image?